# I have question about differences between UITextView and UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextview

It is kind of simple for you guys but i was spending my whole night to figure this out.
my question is that UITextField has a borderStyle Property but UITextView does not have borderStyle Property. what i am confused about is that both UITextField and UITextView using for the text but why one has but not the other one?

Huge thanks in advance.

i have tried searching from the UITextFieled to UIView and UITextView in the same way. but could not figure this out. help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apple design guides implies that text input UI control should have borders instead of text viewing control. That's why, in my opinion, the `UITextField` has this property and the `UITextView` doesn't have it. Anyway `borderStyle` property is a kind of redundant, because you can set view border using layers: `.layer.borderWidth`, `.layer.borderColor`, ...

Comment: i am little bit confused about in saying "text input UI control should have borders instead of text viewing control."

what are the "text input UI control" and "text viewing control" mean?